# how to pass Position wise object data one activity to another using recyclerview and databse in android

Tags: java, android, database, listview, android-recyclerview

I have create the recycerview and this recycerview  display the Person image ,person name and + button when i have press + button change the button image like true.and after recycerview  bottom one button this button click all data show the next activity..

**My Adapter**

```
public class BuildCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BuildCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {
private List<People> peopleList;
private List<People> peopleListCopy;


private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

public BuildCustomAdapter(List<People> buildList) {
    this.peopleList = buildList;
    this.peopleListCopy = new ArrayList<>();
    peopleListCopy.addAll(buildList);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.build_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    People people = peopleList.get(position);

    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(people.getPeopleImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

    holder.ivPeopleImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    holder.tvPersonName.setText(people.getPeopleName());

    holder.button.setSelected(people.isSelected());
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new onSelectListener(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return peopleList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    }
    return mFilter;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // public ImageView ivPeopleImage;
    public TextView tvPersonName;
    public Button button;
    public CircularImageView ivPeopleImage;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivPeopleImage = (CircularImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPerson);
        tvPersonName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonName);
        button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addbn);
    }
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            List<People> filterList = new ArrayList<>();


            for (int i = 0; i < peopleListCopy.size(); i++) {
                if ((peopleListCopy.get(i).getPeopleName().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                    People peopleName = peopleListCopy.get(i);
                    filterList.add(peopleName);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;

        } else {
            results.count = peopleListCopy.size();
            results.values = peopleListCopy;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        peopleList = (List<People>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

private class onSelectListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    int mPosition;

    public onSelectListener(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
        People people = peopleList.get(mPosition);
        people.setSelected(!people.isSelected());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class BulidActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<People> peopleListCopy = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private BuildCustomAdapter buildCustomAdapter;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bulid);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    BuildData();
    peopleListCopy.addAll(peopleList);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    buildCustomAdapter = new BuildCustomAdapter(peopleList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(buildCustomAdapter);

    AddTxt();
    BtnBuildNow();
}

private void BtnBuildNow() {

    Button btnnuildnow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_build_now);

    btnnuildnow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BulidActivity.this, AlertList.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

private void AddTxt() {
    EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
    editTxt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    editTxt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.setFocusable(true);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

    editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (s.length() <= 0) {
                peopleList.clear();
                peopleList.addAll(peopleListCopy);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                buildCustomAdapter = new BuildCustomAdapter(peopleList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(buildCustomAdapter);
            } else {
                buildCustomAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}

private List<People> BuildData() {
    DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    try {
        db.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    if (db.open()) {
        peopleList = db.getPeople();
    }
    return peopleList;

}
```

**Model class**

```
public class People  implements Serializable {
private String peopleImage;
private String peopleName;
private boolean selected;


public void setPeopleName(String peopleName) {
    this.peopleName = peopleName;
}

public String getPeopleName() {
    return peopleName;
}

public void setPeopleImage(String peopleImage) {
    this.peopleImage = peopleImage;
}

public String getPeopleImage() {
    return peopleImage;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

**DatabaseHelper.class**

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/databasename/databases/";
private static final String DB_NAME = "alertme.db";
private final String TABLE_PEOPLE = "people";
private final String TABLE_CATEGORY = "category";
private final String CATEGORY_NAME = "name";
private final String ID = "id";
private final String CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";
private final String PEOPLE_IMAGE = "image";
private final String PEOPLE_NAME = "name";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
    } else {

        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public boolean open() {
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        myDataBase = null;
        return false;
    }
}


public List<People> getPeople(String category_id) {
    List<People> peoples = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from people where category_id = " + category_id, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String peopleName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_NAME));
            String peopleImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_IMAGE));

            People people = new People();
            people.setPeopleName(peopleName);
            people.setPeopleImage(peopleImage);

            peoples.add(people);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("DB", e.getMessage());
    }
    return peoples;
}

public List<Category> getCategory() {
    List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        String query = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY;
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int categoryID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID));
            String categoryName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CATEGORY_NAME));

            Category category = new Category();
            category.setId(categoryID);
            category.setCategoryName(categoryName);

            categoryList.add(category);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("DB", e.getMessage());
    }

    return categoryList;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Intent in below Method,

```
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                build.setSelected(!build.isSelected());
                if (build.isSelected()) {
                    holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_true_icon_new);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, youractivity.class)
    intenet.putExtra("key","value");
    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else
                    holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_button_icon);
            }
        });
```

Comment: how to get model data in next activity?

Comment: replace these line :  intenet.putExtra("key",build.getName());

Comment: i have already replace this line but this data is show to next activity in this activity how to show?

Comment: holder.imageView.setImageResource(build.getImages());
    holder.name.setText(build.getName());

Comment: Where you have to show these data ?? In recycle view ??

Answer (score 1):

First you should implement `Serializable` interface in your `Build` model class like this :-

```
public class Build implements Serializable{
   //Content will be as it is
}
```

Change your clickListener like this :-

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                build.setSelected(!build.isSelected());
                if (build.isSelected()) {
                    holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_true_icon_new);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, youractivity.class)
    intenet.putExtra("build",build);
    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else
                    holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_button_icon);
            }
        });
```

In the `onCreate` method of receiving activity write this :-

```
Build build = (Build) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("build");
```

Comment: I have try your code but some error like  java.lang.NullPointerException in adapter  in this line   Intent intent = new Intent(context, Temp.class);

Comment: May be the `context` would be null. Did you made a saparate `BuildCustomAdapter` file or is it inside your `Activity` ?

Comment: saparate BuildCustomAdapter file.

Comment: Than pass context object inside your `BuildCustomAdapter` file. Modify your `BuildCustomAdapter` `constructor` like this :- 

`public BuildCustomAdapter(List<Build> buildList, Context context) 
{
this.context = context;
this.buildList = buildList; 
this.buildListCopy = new ArrayList<>(); 
buildListCopy.addAll(buildList);
}`

make a `context` in your `BuildCustomAdapter` class like this :-

private Context context;

Comment: also modify your code to this, whenever you are creating object of `BuildCustomAdapter` :- 

`BuildCustomAdapter buildCustomAdapter = new BuildCustomAdapter(buildList, YourActivityName.this);`

Comment: another error like:-Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: every thing's okay but how to get this position in ArrayList in next Activity?

Comment: pass position like this `intent.putExtra("position", position);` and get in into activity like this :- `int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);`

Comment: And one prob i have click the + button direct go to next activity but i have selected item like click + button only change the button image like true and recycerview bottom one button button click event to go to next activity and display the true list in next activity!!!

Comment: Please explain at what event you want to go to another activity ?

Comment: Suppose one listview list view item:-image,name and one button like + button i have click the + button this button is true sign and like i have 10 items to select 5 item okay but this 5 item only change the button image and bottom side one button buildnow after click buildnow this 5 item add  the next activity  using arraylist.

Comment: Are you Understand in my question  yes or no?-@ Rahul Sonpaliya

Comment: as per my understanding, you need to send whole `arraylist` to your activity rather than sending a single object.

Comment: Make an `arraylist` in your `BuildCustomAdapter` class : 
`ArrayList<Build> selectedBuildList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: change the `clickListener` code by this : 
`holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                build.setSelected(!build.isSelected());
                if (build.isSelected()) {
                    holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_true_icon_new);
        selectedBuildList.add(build);
                } else{
                    holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_button_icon);
        selectedBuildList.remove(build);
  }
            }
});`

Comment: make `clickListener` on `buildNow` button like this :- 

`holder.buildnow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, youractivity.class)
  intent.putExtra("selectedBuildList",selectedBuildList);
  context.startActivity(intent);
            }
});`

Comment: and get the `selectedBuildList` in activity like this :- 

`ArrayList<Build> selectedBuildList = (ArrayList<Build>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selectedBuildList");`

Comment: prob is bulidnow button is activity class not in adapter

Comment: And this array how to get all list in next activity?

Comment: for this purpose you need to make `selectedBuildList` arraylist in your `activity` and you also have to change your constructor of `BuildCustomAdapter` to this : `public BuildCustomAdapter(List<Build> buildList, Context context, ArrayList<Build> selectedBuildList) { this.context = context; 
this.selectedBuildList = selectedBuildList;
this.buildList = buildList; this.buildListCopy = new ArrayList<>(); buildListCopy.addAll(buildList); }`

Comment: also modify your code to this, whenever you are creating object of BuildCustomAdapter :- BuildCustomAdapter buildCustomAdapter = new BuildCustomAdapter(buildList, YourActivityName.this, selectedBuildList);

Comment: I have modify all change but how to get list in next activity?

Comment: I've mentioned that in above comments

Comment: I have put this line :-ArrayList<Build> selectedBuildList = (ArrayList<Build>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selectedBuildList"); but java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: are you passing that arraylist inside your `BuildCustomAdapter` file;

Comment: Please properly follow the code i've given in comments.

Comment: code is perfect but not display the selected list in next activity?

Comment: do the arraylist, you've passed in the activity contains any data or is it empty ?

Answer (score 0):

Huge mistak that you register to the click event on your ViewHolder! you will get diffrent position from the actual because when android use notifyItemMoved the viewBindHolder will not be called and than you got the wrong position.

and in the click listener implementation you should pass Intent with your data

Comment: Plz explain i don't know about it  because i have fresher in android?